# Dynamic input length for all input fields

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have been looking for a way to dynamically change the length of the input field in a HTML form.
I have come across the following:

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <title>Example</title>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 window.onload = function() {
 thelink = document.getElementById('MyLink');
 linksize = thelink.value.length;
 if (linksize < 10) thelink.size = 10;
 if (linksize > 50) thelink.size = 50;
 }
 </script>
 </head>

 <body>
 <input id="MyLink" type="text" value="http://www.domain.com/this/is/a/very/long/link/example" />
  </body>

 </html>
```

How would i adapt this to work for every input field on my very large form?

Thanks

Comment: Review your previews asked questions, you need to accept some responses.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, i have done that now.

Answer (score 1):

For your case, I would give the required minimum and maximum as `data-*=` attributes,

For example:

```
<input id="MyLink" data-min="10" data-max="50" type="text" value="http://www.domain.com/this/is/a/very/long/link/example" />
```

Then iterate through the inputs in your form, drawing from the `data` attributes, and checking for the required length.

Answer (score 0):

You can collect elements in a [collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLCollection), either take them from the whole document or some its containing element. You can use e.g. [getElementsByTagName('input');](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName), [getElementsByName('myInput');](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByName) or [getElementsByClassName('shapable_input');](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByClassName) methods, if tags have set the corresponding attribute:

```html
<input name="myInput" class="shapable_input" value="...." />
```

and then all collected tags can be tested in the loop:

```js
window.onload = function() {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    //var linksc = links.getElementsByClassName('link');
    var i, thelink, linksize;
    for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        thelink = links[i];
        linksize = thelink.value.length;
        if (linksize <= 10) {
            thelink.size = 10;
        }
        if (linksize > 10) {
            thelink.size = 50;
        }
    }
};
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/UHcwH/)